# How to find out if the fax number has an email address associated with it?

Tags: php, email, fax

Is it possible to find out if the fax number has an email address associated with it ?, my idea is if the fax number is associated with an email address , then I email instead of faxing .For example if 0864331457 is a fax to email and its email address is me@stackoverflow.com then I must email else I fax . I  really do not know where to start but I would like to build this application using php . Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I doubt such information can be somehow found. That would be a huge privacy issue, since that is clearly private data. So all you can do is ask the recipients, I'd say.

Comment: You might be right hey

Comment: A phone number doesn't even guarantee that it allows faxes, nor having anyone picking up the phone.

Answer (score 1):

As being the developer of [ICTFAX - A Fax to Email gateway](http://ictfax.org/) I can confirm that there is no such way to know about destination email address and its is only possible if remote software / gateway explicitly have this feature.

Comment: Very bad news for me hey